# Can I use Unicode digits for automatic page numbers in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

In an InDesign 2019 document, on my master page, I went to `Type/Insert Special Character/Markers` and selected `Current Page`.  This gives me automatic page numbers but in Western numbers when the character style and indeed the entire rest of the document is in Devanagari.  I went to `Layout/Numbering and Section Options` but I couldn't see anything there that would let me change to Devanagari digits.  Is this not possible?  Is there some other workaround which would let me avoid having to manually renumber pages every time a page is moved or added etc.?

Comment: https://creativepro.com/topic/page-numbering-in-a-localdifferent-language/ and https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/devanagari-script-numerals-in-numbered-para/td-p/11139431 and http://gvsree.blogspot.com/2020/06/devanagari-text-input-problems-in.html

Comment: Thanks.  I've been trying world tools and it seems to do the trick.